# Is the set of elements in a power set equal to that set?

Tags: abstract-algebra

That is, let $D$ be the three element set

$$D=\{a, b, c\}$$

Is the element $\{a, b, c\}$ of the power set of $D$ (denoted $P_D$) the equivalent to the whole set $D$ itself?

Comment: What do you mean by "equivalent"?

Comment: Well, $\{a,b,c\} = \{a,b,c\}$, so ... It seems you are asking if $D$ really equals $D$. Not sure what "equivalent" means for you, though.

Comment: "Equal," or the same

Comment: $\{a,b,c\}$ is equal to $\{a,b,c\}$, right? So yes, of course.

Comment: More generally, $A\in P_A$ for any set $A$.

Comment: Someone should probably say a word or two about extensionality (as an axiom) and why there is a *little* more to this question than just saying that these sets "look the same". Present me however wants to sleep, but future me might type something up...

Answer (score 2):

The question is not entirely that clear, but hopefully this may clear some
things up.

The power set $P_D$ is the set that contains all subsets of $D$. By
definition, $D \subseteq D,$ and thus $D \in P_D.$ In this case,
if $\{a,b,c\} = D,$ then $\{a,b,c\} = D \in P_D.$